# How to read value from xml in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, wcf, sql-server-2000

I want to read the value in xml returned by a WCF service which gets called by a stored procedure. The code below returns a null:

```
declare @xmlValue  varchar(1000)
declare @responseString varchar(100)
declare @idoc int

set @xmlValue = '<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">220</string>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xmlValue

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/*',3)
      WITH (string  varchar(100))

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course - the XML has a **XML namespace** that you're ignoring - you need to pay attention to that!

I would also recommend to use the native XQuery support in SQL Server.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @xmlvalue XML
SET @xmlValue = '<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">220</string>'

-- define the XML namespace
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/' AS ns)
SELECT
    @xmlValue.value('(ns:string)[1]', 'int')  -- and **use** the XML namespace!
```

Comment: thanks marc_s, i forgot to mention that my sqlserver is old...do you know how to do it in sql2000 ?

Comment: @AndrisMudiayi: sorry, no, I don't know how to do this in SQL Server 2000 - this is just way to old now.